# Altair not pulling data from json, which is created with Altair

Tags: python, pandas, altair, python-polars

I am using polars to melt a dataframe, convert pandas, then plot with altair. It is a large dataframe, but I have implemented the techniques present [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data_transformers.html) and [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/large_datasets.html) to manage the large amount of data for altair.

However, the output of the altair plot is empty (shows axis and figure but no data). I suspect that altair is having trouble reading the json data saved to local disk, but at a loss as to why. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

toy example with fabricated pandas dataframe (edited per Nick's request):

```
import os
from toolz.curried import pipe


def json_dir(data, data_dir='/path/to/altairdata'):
    os.makedirs(data_dir, exist_ok=True)
    return pipe(data, alt.to_json(filename=data_dir + '/{prefix}-{hash}.{extension}') )


alt.data_transformers.register('json_dir', json_dir)
alt.data_transformers.enable('json_dir')
alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()

alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [5,8,10]})).mark_point().encode(x='A', y='B')
```

Tried to plot a pandas dataframe with altair boxplot, but altair boxplot is empty.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You might benefit from some of the other ways of plotting large data sets mentioned in the docs, particularly using VegaFusion https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/large_datasets.html

Comment: With version `v5.0.0rc1` there is direct native (but experimental) support for polars dataframe in Vega-Altair.